# Playing large recorded audio files stored in Isolated Storage

Tags: windows-phone-7, microphone

I am recording audio using the XNA Microphone class and saving the recorded data in isolated storage in wav format.
If the length of audio is small my app is working fine.
But as it increases the memory consumed by the app also increases,which drastically slows down the device.
The following code is used to play the audio

```
using (IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = isoStore.OpenFile(AudioFilePath, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    sound = SoundEffect.FromStream(FileStream);  
                    sound.Play();
                }
            }
```

Any suggestion on how to handle the memory issue while playing large audio files.Or how can i save the PCM in other formats (wma,mp3) to reduce the size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SoundEffect` isn't intended for playing long pieces of audio. As the name suggests it is intended for short pieces and also playing lots of them, possibly at the same time.

To play longer pieces of audio you shoudl consider the `MediaElement`.

Comment: +1. that's interesting, I didn't know that. Do you know of any resources that may talk about when to use `SoundEffect` and when to use `MediaElement`?